# How to write SQL Query (Get all Categories and get 10 Products on each Category)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am very new to Database and I want to know raw sql query.
I have 2 tables Category and Product
Product table has foreign_key(category_id).

How can I get all categories with 10 products for each category? So I will display each category name and 10 products on first page.

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price LIMIT 10) as p
ON
 categories.id = p.category_id
```

And also want to query reviews table that product has. How can I join 2 tables(Category with Product(1), Review(2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is a lateral join:

```
SELECT *
FROM categories c LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT p.*
      FROM products p
      WHERE c.id = p.category_id
      ORDER_BY p.price
      LIMIT 10
     ) p
     ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: Thanks!! Can you explain what p.* and ON 1=1 does?

Comment: @freewebwithme . . . `p.*` select all columns from `p`.  `1=1` evaluates to true.

Comment: Sorry to ask.. but how can I query reviews table that product has? I mean 1 more join table..

Comment: @freewebwithme . . . You can add another `join` to the query.  This question has no mention of a `reviews` table.  New questions should be asked as *new* questions.